# How to make template type inference work in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference

Once again, I wish C++ had stronger `typedef`s:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    typedef std::vector<T> List;
};

template<typename T>
void processList(typename A<T>::List list) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    A<int>::List list;
    processList<int>(list); // This works.
    processList(list);      // This doesn't.
}
```

Apparently, the compiler sees `list` as a `std::vector<int>` and not an `A<int>::List`, so it can't match it against the `A<T>::List` that is expected.

In the actual case, it's a longer type name, often repeated, and it's a nuisance. Apart from letting `processList` accept a `vector` instead, is there any way to make template type inference work for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there any way to make template type inference work for me?

No, this is what's called a *non-deducible context*.

However, why do you need this anyway? The idiomatic way to pass sequences around is by iterator:

```
template<typename It>
void processList(It begin, It end) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type T;
    // ....
}

int main() {
    A<int>::List list;
    processList(list.begin(), list.end()); // works now
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that in your question, you pass a `vector` ***by value***, which is a bad thing to do. For iterators, that's fine and even to be preferred.)

However, if you're really desperate, you can have the function deduce any container taking a certain number of template arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename A, template<typename,typename> C>
void processList(C<T,A>& cont) {
    // ....
}
```

Note, however, that this would match *any template with two template arguments*. OTOH, it wouldn't match a container like `std::map`, which has a different number of arguments.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I guess I don't care for "idiomatic" that much, because this is for internal use inside one class only. Passing a (reference to... which I left out in this simplified example) the thing itself makes for shorter code at the call site.

Comment: I passed the vector by value for simplicity of the example. In practice, I pass a const reference, of course. Your update is neat; not that I'll use it (I'm not that desperate) but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: +1 but beware (for the edit) that standard containers don't have a fixed number of arguments --it is implementation defined, the implementation just needs to provide defaults for any extra arguments to the templates so that instantiations that assumes the signatures present in the standard compile.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Use inheritance to create a type that is actually different:

```
template<typename T>
class A : public std::vector<T> {
};
```

Good thing I don't need the non-default constructors in this case.

Comment: Because it's horrible: `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Well he probably won't use it polymorphically through a base class pointer so it's probably not a problem. Thomas, maybe you can post the final code so we can see if it could pose other problems.

Comment: I went with sbi's solution after all, passing iterators around. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution in your case:

```
template <class C>
void processList(C const& list)
{
  typedef typename C::value_type value_type;
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((boost::same_type< C, typename A<value_type>::List >),
    NOT_A_A_LIST_TYPE,
    (C, A<value_type>)
  );
  // do your stuff
}
```

Note that C++0x is coming!

```
template <typename second>
using TypedefName = SomeType<OtherType, second, 5>;
```

I wonder if this would work

```
template <typename value>
using AList = typename A<value>::List;
```